# Iteration of arraylist which contains object

Tags: json, spring-mvc, arraylist

In array index, i am getting `{name=ravi,age=28,course=mca,roll=36}`,
this value is in index 0 position of Arraylist, I want to iterate all values from this index,

```
JSONObject objj=null;
```

I have tried `objj = new JSONObject(arrayData.getBody().get(count));`
And got this value `{name=ravi,age=28,course=mca,roll=36}`,
But when I am using `objj.get("name")` to iterate this, i am getting
`JSONException: JSONObject["name"] not found` error.
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try objj.getString("name") instead